# How to make Material Design Menu (mat-menu) hide on mouseleave

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I succeeded in making the menu appear on `mouseenter`. What I want to do now is make it disappear on the `mouseleave` event of the menu itself. Any ideas on how to make this possible?

```
    <button mat-button [mat-menu-trigger-for]="menu" 
     #menuTrigger="matMenuTrigger" (mouseenter)="menuTrigger.openMenu()">
        TRIGGER BUTTON
    </button>
    <mat-menu #menu="matMenu" [overlapTrigger]="false" 
     (mouseleave)="menuTrigger.closeMenu()">
         <button mat-menu-item [routerLink]="['sources']">
              <mat-icon>view_headline</mat-icon>
              MENU CHOICE
        </button>
    </mat-menu>
```

Comment: Is closeMenu() being called at all? Try making a function in your component that calls `this.menuTrigger.closeMenu()`, and call that function instead.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can do this by wrapping the menu buttons in a `<span>` element:

**HTML:**

```
<button mat-button 
  [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" 
  (mouseenter)="openMyMenu()">
  Trigger
</button>
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu" overlapTrigger="false">
  <span (mouseleave)="closeMyMenu()">
    <button mat-menu-item>Item 1</button>
    <button mat-menu-item>Item 2</button>
  </span>
</mat-menu>
```

**Component:**

```
export class MenuOverviewExample {
  @ViewChild(MatMenuTrigger) trigger: MatMenuTrigger;

  openMyMenu() {
    this.trigger.openMenu();
  } 
  closeMyMenu() {
    this.trigger.closeMenu();
  }  
}
```

---

**Demo (V5):**

[**StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-preufw)

**Material V6:**

[**StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-t8qh6k)

Comment: Until this is officially supported I think this is the best solution. Thank you.

Comment: Can you please update this with an additional functionality so that if I mouseLeave the button itself it turn off the dropdown/menu.

Comment: This (mouseleave) event is not working for latest version of the packages. So can you make the require changes for the latest version of the packages.

Comment: @Und3rTow on mouseout i need to close the menu can you suggest me.

Comment: this trick works, however if I open mat menu and then do not go inside it, then it will be open forever

Comment: @HumbleDolt any findings on your point because i am facing the same issue